# Use two rows from a pandas dataframe to select a location in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have first dataframe `df1` as below. Here `col_b` is any number between h1 and h24 and doesn't contain all of 1 to 24 for each corresponding date:

```
Date        col_b
20101101    h1
20101101    h2
20101101    h3
20101102    h1
20101102    h3
20101103    h2
20101104    h1
20101105    h2
20101105    h3
20101106    h6
20101106    h8
20101106    h24
20101107    h15
```

And second dataframe `df2` as:

```
date        h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 ... h24
20101101    4  6  45 6  7  8  ...  5
20101102    .........................
20101103    .........................
```

I need to select values from `df2` to a list where rows from `df1` match with the location in `df2`.

Currently, I am using `iterrows` to select the row values from `df1` and assigning values in `df2` as 
     `df2.loc[df2['Date] ==row[0], row[1]]` for each row in `df1`.

This is hectic and consuming lot of time. Is there a pythonic or Pandas way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

use `DataFrame.lookup()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3)), 
                  columns=list("ABC"), 
                  index=pd.date_range("2016/01/01", "2016/05/01", freq="MS"))

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":df2.index[np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)],
                   "key": df2.columns[np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)]})

df["value"] = df2.lookup(df["date"], df["key"])
print(df)
```

the result:

```
        date key  value
0 2016-01-01   C      2
1 2016-05-01   A      8
2 2016-01-01   A      8
3 2016-04-01   B      1
4 2016-04-01   C      2
5 2016-03-01   A      2
6 2016-03-01   A      2
7 2016-04-01   B      1
8 2016-05-01   A      8
9 2016-03-01   B      5
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have date as an integer column not as an index. That gives a `KeyError` (with the first value in the `df` column)